# Asterisk call disconnecting if the reload command is executed on asterisk CLI

Tags: asterisk, sip

I execute the reload command from asterisk CLI:

1. All the sip Registry gets unregistered.
2. All the active calls gets disconnected.

I am using asterisk 13.16.0 version.
Is this the default behavior or is there a problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was SIP provider-specific. When `chan_sip` is reloaded and the file `sip.conf` is modified (even if you `touch` the file) then Asterisk Sends the new Register request with newly generated Call-ID again to all the Registry present in `sip.conf` file.
In my case when the SIP provider was getting this new Call-ID then this provider was dropping all the existing SIP sessions, thus causing all Calls to drop.

I fixed this by slightly modifying the reload functionality of `chan_sip` module.

Answer (score 1):

No, sure it is not default. Also there is no way config such behavour, so you have something wrong.

Check

```
asterisk -rx "core show uptime"
```

If you have uptime <1 minute after reload, that mean you core crushed and you have go with "how to debug asterisk crash".

You also can check asterisk logs in /var/log/asterisk/